# Meta Query with date and time on the same Day before given time

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts, meta-query

I have a metaquery for a custom post type "events".
Their start date is stored as a meta field in this format:

```
2016-02-05 19:00:00
```

These are my query args:

```
$args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => 12,
    "paged" => $paged,
    "post_type" => array(
        "event",
        "post"
    ) ,
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "meta_key" => "_thumbnail_id",
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start',
            'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ) ,
    array(
        'key' => 'foreign_language',
        'value' => 0
    ) ,
    array(
        'key' => 'hide_from_most_recent',
        'value' => 0
    )
);
```

The problem: The current date +  time is: `2016-02-05 12:29:16`

This query should return the post with this meta value: `2016-02-05 19:00:00`

Yeterday (one day before this date) it worked. Today it doesn't.
Means:If the day is the same but hour and minute are bigger than now, it does not work, as it should. It seems, that the hour, minute and second are beeing ignored.
I guess the issue is caused by the fact, that I have mixed up time & date.

Is that correct?
How should the query look like, that it works?

Many Thanks

Comment: `19:00:00` is greater than `12:29:16`, you're checking if it's equal or less than.

Comment: @Milo Sorry, was a type. I also added some details to the description.

Comment: Append the time to the current date manually, like `date( 'Y-m-d' ) . ' 00:00:00'`

Comment: @Milo I did that. it did not help. This is the sql query, that runs (reduced) `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND (  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'event_start' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2016-02-05 01:00:00' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'event' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12`

Comment: if it's being cast as date, the time is being stripped and should be irrelevant.

Comment: @Milo So the meta_query won't work, if data and time or stored as one record? I think it could make sense, to split them into two meta fields and extend the meta query, or run a mysql query directly and keep them in one field? Would you agree?

Comment: You can use `DATETIME` or `TIME` types instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error:

```
$args = array(
        "posts_per_page" => 12,
        "paged" => $paged,
        "post_type" => array(
            "event",
            "post"
        ) ,
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "meta_key" => "_thumbnail_id",
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'event_start',
                'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATETIME'
            ) ,
            array(
                'key' => 'event_start',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => 'foreign_language',
            'value' => 0
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => 'hide_from_most_recent',
            'value' => 0
        )
    );
```

It must be `DATETIME` instead of `DATE` as comparing type.